# Calculate the product of multiple lagged values

Tags: r, date, panel-data

I have a following kind of data frame, where the dates can be unbalanced, and there can be some missing data in the RETURN column:

| DATE | CODE | RETURN |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2000-01-01 | ASSET_1 | -0.02 |
| 2000-02-01 | ASSET_1 | 0.02 |
| 2000-03-01 | ASSET_1 | 0.01 |
| 2000-04-01 | ASSET_1 | 0.02 |
| 2000-05-01 | ASSET_1 | 0.03 |
| 2000-06-01 | ASSET_1 | -0.02 |
| 2000-07-01 | ASSET_1 | 0.05 |
| 2000-08-01 | ASSET_1 | -0.04 |
| 2000-09-01 | ASSET_1 | -0.02 |
| 2000-10-01 | ASSET_1 | 0 |
| 2000-11-01 | ASSET_1 | 0.05 |
| 2000-12-01 | ASSET_1 | 0.03 |
| 2000-03-01 | ASSET_2 | NA |
| 2000-04-01 | ASSET_2 | -0.02 |
| 2000-05-01 | ASSET_2 | NA |
| 2000-06-01 | ASSET_2 | -0.03 |
| 2000-07-01 | ASSET_2 | 0.05 |
| 2000-08-01 | ASSET_2 | 0.02 |
| 2000-09-01 | ASSET_2 | -0.03 |
| 2000-10-01 | ASSET_2 | 0.04 |
| 2000-11-01 | ASSET_2 | 0.04 |
| 2000-12-01 | ASSET_2 | 0.04 |
| 2001-01-01 | ASSET_2 | -0.03 |

I would like to calculate the cumulative return for each asset from T - 12 to T - 2. So at 2001-01-01 for example, the cumulative return would be from 2000-01-01 to 2000-11-01 and add it in a new column.

So, for ASSET_1 at 2001-01-01, I would get the value of 0.98 * 1.02 * 1.01 * 1.02 * 1.03 * 0.98 * 1.05 * 0.96 * 0.98 * 1.00 * 1.05 - 1 = 0.08

In the case such return couldnt be calculated (NA values or not enough periods to calculate such figure) the cumulative return would be NA.

I couldn't figure this out without creating a bunch of lag(RETURN) columns. Is there a simpler way?

Answer (score 1):

A quick and dirty solution (which assumes that there are no gaps in time) is to calculate the cumulative product with `cumprod` and then lag that only for the 13th row or more (T0) for each asset:

```r
library("dplyr")
library("magrittr")
library("tibble")
data <-
  structure(list(DATE = structure(c(10957, 10988, 11017, 11048, 
                                    11078, 11109, 11139, 11170,
                                    11201, 11231, 11262, 11292, 11323, 
                                    11017, 11048, 11078, 11109, 11139,
                                    11170, 11201, 11231, 11262, 
                                    11292, 11323), class = "Date"),
               CODE = c("ASSET_1", "ASSET_1", "ASSET_1", "ASSET_1", "ASSET_1",
                        "ASSET_1", "ASSET_1", "ASSET_1", "ASSET_1", "ASSET_1",
                        "ASSET_1", "ASSET_1", "ASSET_1",
                        "ASSET_2", "ASSET_2", "ASSET_2",
                        "ASSET_2", "ASSET_2", "ASSET_2", "ASSET_2", "ASSET_2",
                        "ASSET_2", "ASSET_2", "ASSET_2"),
               RETURN = c(-0.02, 0.02, 0.01, 0.02, 0.03, -0.02, 0.05, -0.04,
                       -0.02, 0, 0.05, 0.03, 0.01, NA, -0.02, NA, -0.03, 0.05, 0.02,
                       -0.03, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, -0.03)),
            class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -24L))
want <-
  data %>%
  group_by(CODE) %>%
  arrange(DATE, .by_group = TRUE) %>%
  mutate(row_in_g = seq_len(n())) %>%
  mutate(cumulative_return = if_else(row_in_g >= 13,
                                     lag(cumprod(RETURN + 1), 2) - 1,
                                     NA_real_)) %>%
  select(-row_in_g) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Which gives:

```r
> print(data, n = 30)
# A tibble: 24 x 3
   DATE       CODE    RETURN
   <date>     <chr>    <dbl>
 1 2000-01-01 ASSET_1  -0.02
 2 2000-02-01 ASSET_1   0.02
 3 2000-03-01 ASSET_1   0.01
 4 2000-04-01 ASSET_1   0.02
 5 2000-05-01 ASSET_1   0.03
 6 2000-06-01 ASSET_1  -0.02
 7 2000-07-01 ASSET_1   0.05
 8 2000-08-01 ASSET_1  -0.04
 9 2000-09-01 ASSET_1  -0.02
10 2000-10-01 ASSET_1   0   
11 2000-11-01 ASSET_1   0.05
12 2000-12-01 ASSET_1   0.03
13 2001-01-01 ASSET_1   0.01
14 2000-03-01 ASSET_2  NA   
15 2000-04-01 ASSET_2  -0.02
16 2000-05-01 ASSET_2  NA   
17 2000-06-01 ASSET_2  -0.03
18 2000-07-01 ASSET_2   0.05
19 2000-08-01 ASSET_2   0.02
20 2000-09-01 ASSET_2  -0.03
21 2000-10-01 ASSET_2   0.04
22 2000-11-01 ASSET_2   0.04
23 2000-12-01 ASSET_2   0.04
24 2001-01-01 ASSET_2  -0.03
> 
> print(want, n = 30)
# A tibble: 24 x 4
   DATE       CODE    RETURN cumulative_return
   <date>     <chr>    <dbl>             <dbl>
 1 2000-01-01 ASSET_1  -0.02           NA     
 2 2000-02-01 ASSET_1   0.02           NA     
 3 2000-03-01 ASSET_1   0.01           NA     
 4 2000-04-01 ASSET_1   0.02           NA     
 5 2000-05-01 ASSET_1   0.03           NA     
 6 2000-06-01 ASSET_1  -0.02           NA     
 7 2000-07-01 ASSET_1   0.05           NA     
 8 2000-08-01 ASSET_1  -0.04           NA     
 9 2000-09-01 ASSET_1  -0.02           NA     
10 2000-10-01 ASSET_1   0              NA     
11 2000-11-01 ASSET_1   0.05           NA     
12 2000-12-01 ASSET_1   0.03           NA     
13 2001-01-01 ASSET_1   0.01            0.0782
14 2000-03-01 ASSET_2  NA              NA     
15 2000-04-01 ASSET_2  -0.02           NA     
16 2000-05-01 ASSET_2  NA              NA     
17 2000-06-01 ASSET_2  -0.03           NA     
18 2000-07-01 ASSET_2   0.05           NA     
19 2000-08-01 ASSET_2   0.02           NA     
20 2000-09-01 ASSET_2  -0.03           NA     
21 2000-10-01 ASSET_2   0.04           NA     
22 2000-11-01 ASSET_2   0.04           NA     
23 2000-12-01 ASSET_2   0.04           NA     
24 2001-01-01 ASSET_2  -0.03           NA
```

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late response

Thanks for your answer. I couldn't get this to work reliably sadly, so I ended up taking a different, easier approach in doing this, i.e, calculating the period return directly from a return index

Comment: No problem. You should maybe add your new approach as an answer in case someone else is trying to do the same?

Comment: My approach was simply taking my raw data and calculating the return from the return index, i.e. (RI(t-2) - RI(t-12)) / RI(t-12) instead